# Insert DataGridView's Column's data into Combo Box

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, ms-access-2007

I am writing this program in which I am required to store a particular column's data into a Combo Box. There is only one column in a database's table and it needs to be populated in a Combo Box.

The Code I am trying is;

```
private void populateList()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            cmbUserNames.Items.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        }  
    }
```

I have created a DataGridView which populates itself from the data at the startup of the form. I have create the above method and when I call it in the FormLoad event, after when the DataGridView has loaded, it throws an exception.

I look forward to the solutions. Thanks!

Comment: what exception do you actually get? Since you said only one column in the database, why Cells[2]?

Comment: Why `DataGridView` is required when you have to populate data in `comboBox`?

Comment: Why cant you directly load the `ComboBox` from Database's table?

Comment: Dear Chinz! I have tried to input [0], [1] also but it still throws an exception. Exception is "Index was out of range. Must be a non-negative and less than the size of the collection". There is one record already in the table.

Comment: Dear Khan! I thought it would be 'easy' to retrieve the data from the DataGridView. If there is any other way for getting the data into a combo box, please let me hear it. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know why you have to get the data from the gridview, but you should have populate the data like what @HassanNisar said?

Comment: cmbUserNames.DataSource = yourDataSource or datatable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can try use the following:

```
private void populateList()
{       
    cmbUserNames.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    //In the event you need specify column to be displayed/or value add the following
    cmbUserNames.ValueMember = "ColumnToBevalue";
    cmdUserNames.DisplayMember = "ColumnToDisplay";
}
```